# AppStore Metadata rejection Guideline 2.3

Tags: ios, apple-developer

So been trying to upload an app to the AppStore am keep getting rejected with the message below. Tried adding armv7 to the UIRequiredDeviceCapability but still no difference

> Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata

> We were unable to install the app on iPhone and iPad. The
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a
> way that the app will not install on iPhone and iPad .
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
> key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your
> app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device.
> Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are
> required and false if they must not be present on the device.
>
> Resources
>
> Please review the Technical Q&A 1397: Understanding the
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key for information on the
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.
>
> You may also wish to review the dictionary keys table in
> the "Declaring the Required Device Capabilities" section of the App
> Programming Guide for iOS.
>
> Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT
> require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect
> to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve
> completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and
> we will continue the review.

below is my Info.plist
[image]

Comment: please share your plist screenshot?

Comment: @MohitKumar added the plist to the screenshoot

Answer (score 1):

Delete `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` from your `Info.plist` if you don't really need it.

Check out [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uirequireddevicecapabilities) for the available values or more info.

Comment: Tried that still no difference

Comment: That does not make sense. you say you removed this key and still got the same rejection from Apple? (that `The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on iPhone and iPad`)

Comment: Yeah the first build didn't have that and it got rejected well currently removed it again. And removing everything related to the ipad

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/98481 ‍♂️